# Restriction 10km of interpolation radius in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I am trying to use the Grid (Interpolation) tool from Analysis Menu in QGIS 2.18 for a small set of very few, sparsely ditributed points (they are centroids of municipalities and the quantity is population potential). But for the radius parameters of IDW method, I can't define values more than 10000m. I wonder, is it on purpose or is it a bag on the code?

Answer (score 3):

Strange, using QGIS 2.18.2 (Win7 64-bit), the radius limit for me is `65000`. However, you could also try accessing the same tool from the **Processing Toolbox** and see if the radius limit there lets you go above `10000`:

[image: Grid tools]

Comment: You can actually manually edit the GDAL commands. So there is the pen next to the text at the bottom, where you could manually enter another value.

Comment: @Vesanto - Thanks, good point! I tend to overlook the pencil... :)

Comment: @Joseph: I use Win10 64bit (upgraded from Win7). I know about the Processing Toolbox, but I use this for educational purposes and the procedure for this is a bit more complicated. Haven't tried though to check if the restriction is the same there..

Comment: @Vesanto: I tried that but it also doesn't let me put more than 10000!

Answer (score 1):

I might be blind, but I cannot see the Grid Interpolation from the analysis menu nor from `Raster -> interpolation -> interpolation Plugin`:

[image]

[image]

Thus, I am not sure what radius parameter of IDW are you talking about.

Comment: The tool the OP mentioned is part of the **GdalTools** plugin :). Perhaps it wasn't enabled?